# How to imitate scroll down on a webpage using ruby mechanize?

Tags: ruby, scroll, mechanize

I have a web page, with ajax effect - the new elements apperars, when the user scroll down the page. I want to parse all this elements, with ruby mechanize. Any suggesions?

Comment: Figure out the ajax urls, make the requests and parse the responses. If you want more help you will need to post an url.

Comment: the url is http://vk.com/search?c[photo]=1&c[section]=people&c[sex]=1&c[status]=6

Comment: Yes, my suggestion will work with that url.